# Extracting mpk file into MXD and its shapefiles and keep connection between them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, mxd, map-package

I have many mpk files, which are open by ArcMap.

I would like to have them as mxd files and a folder with the shapefiles that come with them, and when you open the MXD file the shapefiles should be already loaded there.

Is there a way to automatically do this for all mpk files and not one by one?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the help file on [Extracting packages](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/extract-package.htm) there is sample code that will automate the extraction from many packages for you. You just need to scroll down to the code sample section, it's all in the help file.